# Comparing RGB histograms: plt.hist, np.histogram, and cv2.compareHist

Tags: opencv, numpy, histogram

From two jpeg files I've used PIL to create two np arrays of rgb values, one has dimension n x 3, the other m x 3. The question is how to feed these two arrays into cv2.compareHist(h1, h2, method). Here is the relevant part of my code, after creating my np arrays called "bob1" and "mark1":

```
-----
h1 = np.histogram(bob1)
ph1 = plt.hist(bob1)
plt.show() #looks nice, get 3 bars per bin

h2 = np.histogram(mark1)
ph2 = plt.hist(mark1)

#the problem occurs here:
d = cv2.compareHist(h1,h2, cv2.cv.CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA)
print d
---
```

the error I get is:

```
d = cv2.compareHist(h1,h2, cv2.cv.CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA)

TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

I get the same error if I replace h1 with ph1 and h2 with ph2 in the last line in the above code.

Help is appreciated. Eventually I want to iterate this procedure over several h_i's and return a list of "d" values for each pair of h_i, h_j.

ps. here are some sample values:

```
bob1.shape = (9223, 3)
mark1.shape = (7861,3) 
#could make shapes equal via deleting rows

ph1 =[   91   758  1337  1669  1701  1595  1829  2759  5395 10535] 
ph2= [   81    363  1402  2042  1679  1777  1570  2051  2396 10222]
#here, ph1.shape == ph2.shape is True and ph1.shape = (10,)
```

Comment: I've also checked that even if bob1.shape = mark1.shape, errors are still present, such as:
H1.type() == H2.type() && H1.type() == CV_32F in function compareHist. 

Perhaps the following is related to my underlying problem?:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/6695/comparehist-problem-type-cv_32f/

Comment: Hi, not used the python interface, but if you want to compare different sized histograms you can try EMD distance http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=comparehist#emd

Comment: Also try converting to floats before comparing

Comment: why not use cv2.calcHist() function from OpenCV?

Comment: compareHist() expects two numpy arrays, but you are passing a tuple. (ph1 should have been a tuple of three numpy arrays)

Comment: @Abid, thank you; I will try the proposals. Regarding ph1, it is the result of summing each of the three bars (r,g,b) per bin, hence it represents a summed version of the original histogram. Even so, I'm surprised that ph1 and ph2 do not work since they are the same size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the error that you’re encountering is that OpenCV's `cv2.compareHist` function expects an Nx1 column array of bin counts, while the Numpy [`histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) function returns a tuple of the form `(bin_counts, bin_edges)`. (See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_begins/py_histogram_begins.html#histograms-getting-started) to get some info about the OpenCV histogram functionality as exposed via Python bindings.)

If you’re comparing colour images via their histograms the multidimensional [`histogramdd`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html) function is actually more appropriate, as [`histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) actually flattens the input array before binning.

In both cases the following function will map the Numpy histogram output to a corresponding OpenCV-compatible form:

```
def np_hist_to_cv(np_histogram_output):
    counts, bin_edges = np_histogram_output
    return counts.ravel().astype('float32')
```

So given random data of the form you describe:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

bob1 = np.random.rand(100, 3).astype('float32')
mark1 = np.random.rand(100, 3).astype('float32')
```

You can construct 3D (i.e. colour-space) histograms as follows:

```
h1 = np.histogramdd(bob1)
h2 = np.histogramdd(mark1)
```

And use the above function to pass the arguments to the OpenCV `compareHist` function as follows:

```
d = cv2.compareHist(np_hist_to_cv(h1), np_hist_to_cv(h2),
                    cv2.cv.CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA)
print d
0.932737905309
```